# How to Apply a Migration that comes "Before" Newer Migrations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am not even sure how to phrase this one. I have migrations applied to the db: Migration One. Migration Two. Migration Three. I just pulled a "Migration 2.5" - if I try to revert to migration Two and `Update-Database', the db updates successfully and says there are pending changes. These "pending changes" are Migration 2.5, even though it's been applied - EF wants me to add them again.

Now, normally, I get around the problem like this - revert to Migration One or Two, delete Migration 2.5, apply changes, and create a new "Migration 4" that comes LAST. This way the problem is avoided. However, I cannot change around the order of the migrations now. How do I solve this?

---

Edit: I think it's important to note that my db does work properly. If there is a db/code mismatch, EF throws an error stating so - this isn't happening. The problem is that the moment I do need to `Add-Migration` with a legitimate change, it will try to duplicate the "2.5" changes along with the actual legitimate changes.

Comment: Why are you creating a new migration that for some reason sits between two existing ones?  Shouldn't migration 2.5 be Migration Four?

Comment: 1. Be me, make sweet sequential migrations. 2. My senior dev decided he wants to merge his old branches. Shoves them in build with aforementioned migration. 3. I pull these changes from github, including all migration. 4. He is too cool to explain how to make it work.

Comment: Why would the order matter whether it was yours or theirs first?  Sounds to me that if they are somehow dependent on each other that it doesn't matter the order and what you really need to do is resolve the conflict instead.

Comment: Is that a blind guess Matt? Because I have found that the order always matters and this problem will ALWAYS occur when migrations are out of order.

Comment: have you tried merging them in the migration class? If the two changes are agnostic of each other (different tables, relationships, etc.) you should be able to combine them into one DbMigration.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - which changes? By "merging," do you just mean editing the migration file by hand?

Comment: Yes. Assuming you have a `20150811xxx_25.cs` (senior dev's migration) and a `20150811xxx_30.cs` (your migration) you should be able to move your changes into the senior dev's, remove your changes and apply an update. After that, your migrationhistory table should align and you can move forward.

Comment: Oh yea, I can do that no prob, and create merge conflicts for everyone who hasn't.

Comment: Once you merge them, everyone will have _that_ DbMigration (and a subsequent `Update-Database` will bring their environment current). How many people are creating migrations? Sounds like you need to work out who's working on what.

Comment: @BradChristie haha about 16 + consultants in diff time zones, and yea we do, but I don't have a say in that

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really an answer to the original question - I have not found a way to make EF recognize that it has applied an "out of order" migration. However, here are two ways to get around the problem, which, more specifically, is getting the quoted error when trying to pull an "out of order" migration:

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.

1. Create an empty "Fix" migration - this is a fairly simple, but dirty solution. You simply run `Add-Migration`. You then delete  migration actions, so you should be left with empty blocks like so:

   ```
   public override void Up()
   {
   }

   public override void Down()
   {
   }
   ```

   You then run `Update-Database`. The reason this works is simple - as pointed out earlier, EF the "out of order" migration was not applied, despite the fact that it was actually applied the first time you ran `Update Database`- note that you should be able to verify that it was applied with `Get-Migrations`. Anyway, for some reason EF wants to duplicate it, but will be placated by an empty migration instead. Makes no sense to me.

This solution is undesirable as it leaves a pointless migration, but may be your only route if you cannot easily get to the environments which the out of order migration has already been pushed to.

2. 

a. `Update-Database Target-Migration "The Migration Before The Out of Order One"` to revert to the migration before this problem began.
b. Now manual delete the "Out of Order" migration file from your migrations folder.
c. Run `Update-Database` again to bring your db current with all changes EXCEPT the "Out of Order" migration.
d.Run `Add-Migration` - this will recreate the "Out of Order" migration you deleted in the beginning, but in its proper,or at least functional, place.
e. Run `Update-Database` and you are done.

Note that this will create problems unless synchronized with your team for reasons I am too lazy to go into. #2 is better, but #1 is easier and faster.

P.S. Stackoverflow nested list syntax is too much for me to handle.